# How do I get a button to open another activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've added a button to my activity XML file and I can't get it to open my other activity. Can some please tell me step by step on how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of code? I guess you didn't set an `OnClickListener` on your Button.

Comment: please post the relevent code.

Comment: If you are new to programming and trying to go With Android Studio - try to learn the basics first, in your case Java Programming Language would be a good start. Then Learn about Markup language - XML. Then once you Uderstand it - you can go to [Android Studio Website](https://developer.android.com/sdk) and start reading just like everyone else does. Then after learning about it you should try create some basic projects. There are a lot of videos on Youtube to get you going. In my opinion you come here on stack overflow and ask question if you stuck

Comment: Then you have to show your work, show that you are not just trying to get a code snippet from the community. I tutored some students that would ask me to solve it for them but they were not interesting in learning how it works or learn anything. Instead they would come back when they have a problem so I can just solve it again. Not only this is unfair to occupy one's time's and effort but it is also keeps you coming back and asking simple questions that you could have answered your self if you took the time. [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In a long run if you solve at least a dozen of those questions you will learn how to fish, instead of coming to eat fish that people might get for you. This is a great community and there are a lot of professionals here willing to share their great experience with others, but we all have to keep it clean and all work hard to learn and be helpful to others!

Answer (score 90):

A.  Make sure your other activity is declared in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="MyOtherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

**All activities must be declared in manifest**, even if they do not have an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) assigned to them.

---

B.  In your MainActivity do something like this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button);    

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

### Using an OnClickListener

Inside your `Activity` instance's `onCreate()` method you need to first find your `Button` by it's id using `findViewById()` and then set an `OnClickListener` for your button and implement the `onClick()` method so that it starts your new `Activity`.

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_buttons_id);

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){                        
        startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class));
    }
});
```

This is probably most developers preferred method. However, there is a common alternative.

### Using onClick in XML

Alternatively you can use the `android:onClick="yourMethodName"` to declare the method name in your `Activity` which is called when you click your `Button`, and then declare your method like so;

```
public void yourMethodName(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class));
}
```

Also, don't forget to declare your new `Activity` in your `manifest.xml`. I hope this helps.

References;

- [Starting Another Activity (Official API Guide)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: Is there a difference between these two ways? In the first way we can control it dynamically I guess, any advantage else? (for me as a noob Android programmer)

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk as you point out the first method can be dynamically changed or updated, but the second requires less code and is slightly neater. Otherwise they're just two alternate methods of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

If you declared your button in the xml file similar to this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next activity"
        android:onClick="goToActivity2"
        />
```

then you can use it to change the activity by putting this at the java file:

```
public void goToActivity2 (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note that my second activity is called "Main2Activity"

Answer (score 4):

use the following code to have a button, in android studio, open an already existing activity.

```
Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR BUTTONS ID GOES HERE);

StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, YOUR ACTIVITY'S ID GOES HERE.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Button T=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_timer);
T.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YOURACTIVITY.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Write code on xml file.

```
<Button android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Click"/>
```

Write Code in your java file

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Secondclass.class));
           /* if you want to finish the first activity then just call
            finish(); */
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the same that user9876226 answered. 
The only differemce is, that I don't usually use the onClickListener. Instead I write following in the xml-file: `android:onClick="open"`

`open` is the function, that is bound to the button.
Then just create the function open() in your activity class. When you click on the button, this function will be called :) 
Also, I think this way is more confortable than using the listener.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following steps:

1. insert new layout xml in folder layout
2. rename window2
3. add new button and add this line:  android:onClick="window2"

*mainactivity.java*

```
public void openWindow2(View v) {
        //call window2
        setContentView(R.layout.window2);           
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not open another activity. It will change the content of the current activity.

Comment: It 'works' but you can't use the back button to return to the previous screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use following steps to add the new activity (Manifest file will be automatically update) 
*File > New > Activity > Empty Activity*

In your ***MainActivity.java*** file add the following code inside ***protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)***.
Make sure you call ***finish();*** function at the end. So when you tap the Back button, it will not go back to the previous activity.

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button);    

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
});
```