# Switching Activity with onClick Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to make my button id = buttonToScreen2 to go to my second activity screen name = FullscreenActivity2 but somewhere in my code below I have an error.

> My "main" FullscreenActivity.java

```
Button goToScreen2Function = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToScreen2);

goToScreen2Function.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClickToScreen2(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

> XML

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonToScreen2" style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/titleScreen1"
            android:onClick="onClickToScreen2"/>
```

> Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullscreenActivity2"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen_activity2"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
</activity>
```

New to Android Dev, tried to follow the tutorial and answers but didn't work. 
[How do I get a button to open another activity in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610527/how-do-i-get-a-button-to-open-another-activity-in-android-studio)
Thanks in advance!

```
//Line 123 is goToScreen2Function.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
Error:(123, 43) error: <identifier> expected 
Error:(123, 44) error: illegal start of type
Error:(123, 47) error: ')' expected
Error:(123, 52) error: ';' expected
Error:(123, 53) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(124, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(124, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(124, 37) error: ';' expected
Error:(124, 44) error: ';' expected
Error:(128, 6) error: illegal start of type
```

> Full Code
>       package com.scorekeeper;

```
import com.scorekeeper.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;


private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
}

Button goToScreen2Function = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToScreen2);

goToScreen2Function.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClickToScreen2(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}

View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to be somewhere in my .java file See attached error on compile

Comment: Post complete code of `FullscreenActivity`. As you have combined `onClickToScreen2` and Button's `onClick` with Listener.

Comment: Sorry could you explain this line a little more "As you have combined onClickToScreen2 and Button's onClick with Listener." Should I be using onClick(View v) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From your compiler error its seems you have written wrong method code.**

Now, as you have already declared `android:onClick="onClickToScreen2"` Button's onClick in xml layout file, no need of again write **Button's onClick** With `onClickListner`. Just simple as a class level method write your button's `onClickToScreen2` method like,

Replace below code lines

```
Button goToScreen2Function = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToScreen2);

goToScreen2Function.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClickToScreen2(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

with below code lines

```
 public void onClickToScreen2(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, FullscreenActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: See my logcat issue when I click on the button now though

Comment: @Codeconuts - both are feasible ways. Use one of the form as simplicity of your code and better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**In your main activity i.e. FullscreenActivity.java try using this code:**

```
    Button goToScreen2Function = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToScreen2);

goToScreen2Function.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClickToScreen2(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullscreenActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```