# How do i get a button to open a new activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd seen this asked in many, many places and have tried to follow the instructions given to no avail. I dont know if the questions are old, i'm doing things incorrectly or if my android studio program isnt working. What i want to do is to **only** open a new activity when a button is clicked. I'm very new to developing android applications.

I've recently tried to follow the answer provided here: [How do I get a button to open another activity in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610527/how-do-i-get-a-button-to-open-another-activity-in-android-studio)

OnClick on the button is called "goTutorials"
My original activity is called home (Not mainActivity)
The new one is called tutorials.

This is what i added from trying to follow the link above:
In home's java file:

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(home.this, tutorials.class));
    }
});
```

In manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="tutorials"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It wont recognize btn or the v in onClick(View v)

Comment: This is not Android Studio, this is Java. Welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Method 1**

**Use the `onclick` attribute in XML** (so that whenever you click the button, defined method will trigger)

Step 1. - go to the XML where you button is(`activity_home`) & add

```
<Button
............
android:onClick="gotoTutorial"/>
```

Step 2. - then go to the `home.Java` & add following

```
public void gotoTutorial(View v){
    Intent tutorialPage = new Intent (this, tutorials.class);
    startActivity(tutorialPage);
}
```

---

### **Method 2**

**Use the `setOnClickListener`**

Step 1. -

```
 //create the link to the button in the interface
 btn_tutorial = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tutorial_button); 

 btn_tutorial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent tutorialPage = new Intent (this, tutorials.class);
            startActivity(tutorialPage);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample app please see the code below.
You need to specify information of all activities in Manifest file.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nextech.startnewactivity">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TutorialsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorials"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Launcher activity is MainActivity.java

```
package com.nextech.startnewactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button startTutorials = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startTutorials);
    startTutorials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent tutorialsActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TutorialsActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(tutorialsActivityIntent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.nextech.startnewactivity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Hello World! This is main activity!" />

<Button android:id="@+id/startTutorials"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Start Tutorials"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TutorialsActivity.java

```
package com.nextech.startnewactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TutorialsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorials);
}

}
```

activity_tutorials.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.nextech.startnewactivity.TutorialsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tutorials">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is tutorial activity"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest file is not displaying, but make sure you add the activity in your manifest `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `application` field. Here's an example from Google: [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
<application ... >
...
<activity
    android:name="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
</activity>
```

Otherwise, the method you're using should be correct. You create an intent to the class of the Activity you want to start.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, tutorials.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure you have the necessary methods such as `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` Overrided.

Note that in the sample above `android:name=""` is your activity's full path name to the class (without .class/.java) and label is going to be the action toolbar string you'll see. In the `<meta-data/>` section you can alter the `android:value=""` to the starting activity's name so that will need to change based on what you call it.

Finally, make sure it has an XML view to go with it, as it gets inflated in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` call.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_here);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your activity file write this

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(home.this, tutorials.class));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
   <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/button_send"
          android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

.Java class

```
  /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityYouWantToOpen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```