# create button on xml file (not new activity) and open new activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new in android studio and currently creating an app which will retrieve data from existing db of sqlite. based on what I'd found is to create a layout file  (not by creating new empty activity) to design on how the display the data. But in the layout, I want the button to open new activity, but somehow it didn't and I didn't found any solution so far. and the image also didn't appeared. This is the code:

DataPOI.java

```
public class DataPOI {
    private int id;
    private String category;
    private String name;
    private String hour;
    private String phone_number;
    private String address;
    private String website;
    private int fee_adult_standard;
    private int fee_child_standard;
    private int fee_senior_standard;
    private int fee_adult_MyKad;
    private int fee_child_MyKid;
    private int fee_senior_MyKad;
    private int fee_student_standard;
    private int fee_student_MyKad;
    private String description;
    private byte[] photo;
    private String coordinate;
    private String door;
    private String parking1;
    private String parking2;

public DataPOI(int id, String category, String name, String hour, String phone_number,
               String address, String website, int fee_adult_standard, int fee_child_standard,
               int fee_senior_standard, int fee_adult_MyKad, int fee_child_MyKid,
               int fee_senior_MyKad, int fee_student_standard, int fee_student_MyKad,
               String description, byte[] photo, String coordinate, String door,
               String parking1, String parking2) {
    this.id = id;
    this.category = category;
    this.name = name;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
    this.address = address;
    this.website = website;
    this.fee_adult_standard = fee_adult_standard;
    this.fee_child_standard = fee_child_standard;
    this.fee_senior_standard = fee_senior_standard;
    this.fee_adult_MyKad = fee_adult_MyKad;
    this.fee_child_MyKid = fee_child_MyKid;
    this.fee_senior_MyKad = fee_senior_MyKad;
    this.fee_student_standard = fee_student_standard;
    this.fee_student_MyKad = fee_student_MyKad;
    this.description = description;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
    this.door = door;
    this.parking1 = parking1;
    this.parking2 = parking2;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(String hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public String getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}

public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public int getFee_adult_standard() {
    return fee_adult_standard;
}

public void setFee_adult_standard(int fee_adult_standard) {
    this.fee_adult_standard = fee_adult_standard;
}

public int getFee_child_standard() {
    return fee_child_standard;
}

public void setFee_child_standard(int fee_child_standard) {
    this.fee_child_standard = fee_child_standard;
}

public int getFee_senior_standard() {
    return fee_senior_standard;
}

public void setFee_senior_standard(int fee_senior_standard) {
    this.fee_senior_standard = fee_senior_standard;
}

public int getFee_adult_MyKad() {
    return fee_adult_MyKad;
}

public void setFee_adult_MyKad(int fee_adult_MyKad) {
    this.fee_adult_MyKad = fee_adult_MyKad;
}

public int getFee_child_MyKid() {
    return fee_child_MyKid;
}

public void setFee_child_MyKid(int fee_child_MyKid) {
    this.fee_child_MyKid = fee_child_MyKid;
}

public int getFee_senior_MyKad() {
    return fee_senior_MyKad;
}

public void setFee_senior_MyKad(int fee_senior_MyKad) {
    this.fee_senior_MyKad = fee_senior_MyKad;
}

public int getFee_student_standard() {
    return fee_student_standard;
}

public void setFee_student_standard(int fee_student_standard) {
    this.fee_student_standard = fee_student_standard;
}

public int getFee_student_MyKad() {
    return fee_student_MyKad;
}

public void setFee_student_MyKad(int fee_student_MyKad) {
    this.fee_student_MyKad = fee_student_MyKad;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getCoordinate() {
    return coordinate;
}

public void setCoordinate(String coordinate) {
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
}

public String getDoor() {
    return door;
}

public void setDoor(String door) {
    this.door = door;
}

public String getParking1() {
    return parking1;
}

public void setParking1(String parking1) {
    this.parking1 = parking1;
}

public String getParking2() {
    return parking2;
}

public void setParking2(String parking2) {
    this.parking2 = parking2;
}
}
```

ListPOIadapter.java

```
public class ListPOIadapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<DataPOI> mPOIList;

public ListPOIadapter(Context mContext, List<DataPOI> mPOIList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPOIList = mPOIList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPOIList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mPOIList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return mPOIList.get(i).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.data_layout, null);
    //edit below this
    ImageView myPhoto = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView myName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView myHour = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.operational_hour);
    TextView myContact = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
    TextView myWebsite = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.website);
    TextView myAddress = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.address);

    //myPhoto.setI(mPOIList.get(i).getPhoto());
    myName.setText(mPOIList.get(i).getName());
    myHour.setText(mPOIList.get(i).getHour());
    myContact.setText(mPOIList.get(i).getPhone_number());
    myWebsite.setText(mPOIList.get(i).getWebsite());
    myAddress.setText(mPOIList.get(i).getAddress());
    return v;
}
}
```

AmusementPark.java

```
public class AmusementPark extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lvPOI;
private ListPOIadapter adapter;
private List<DataPOI> mPOIList;
private AmusementPark_Helper mDBHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amusement_park);
    lvPOI = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_product);
    mDBHelper = new AmusementPark_Helper(this);

    //Check existis database
    File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(AmusementPark_Helper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    //Get product list in db when db exists
    mPOIList = mDBHelper.getListPOI();

    //Init adapter
    adapter = new ListPOIadapter(this, mPOIList);

    //Set adapter for listview
    lvPOI.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private boolean copyDatabase (Context context) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(AmusementPark_Helper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = AmusementPark_Helper.DBLOCATION + AmusementPark_Helper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.v("Amusement Park", "DB copied");
        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

AmusementPark_Helper.java

```
public class AmusementPark_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DBNAME = "placeofinterest.sqlite";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.example.lenovo.welcome.ListHelper";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public AmusementPark_Helper (Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}

public void openDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if(mDatabase != null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<DataPOI> getListPOI() {
    DataPOI placeofinterest = null;
    List<DataPOI> poiList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM amusement_park", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        //below is depends on data type of each column
        placeofinterest = new DataPOI(
                cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6), cursor.getInt(7), cursor.getInt(8),
                cursor.getInt(9), cursor.getInt(10), cursor.getInt(11),
                cursor.getInt(12), cursor.getInt(13), cursor.getInt(14),
                cursor.getString(15), cursor.getBlob(16), cursor.getString(17),
                cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20));
        poiList.add(placeofinterest);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return poiList;
}
}
```

data_layout.xml (created not by using "create new empty activity")

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="#89cff0">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:text="Name of POI"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/operational_hour"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:text="Operational Hours"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/operational_hour"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:text="Contact Number"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/website"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Website"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/website"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Address"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_description"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/address"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_entrance_fee"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/address"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_description"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Entrance Fee"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_nearest_me"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_entrance_fee"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Nearest Me"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_take_me_there"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_entrance_fee"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_nearest_me"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Take Me There"
    android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, how to open new activity from a button which as no .java? I tried to create a new activity and copy paste from the data_layout.xml but it still not working. I hope my explanation is quite clear. and please help me. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to open a new screen which has no activity.java file, only for layout.xml file?

Comment: No. What I means is, I have only layout.xml and wish to open new activity (which consist of .java and .xml)

Answer (score 0):

In your AmusementPark.java file, change

```
if(false == database.exists()) {
```

to

```
if(database.exists == false) {
```

Also verify the paths are correct. See this very similar article: [How do I get a button to open another activity in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610527/how-do-i-get-a-button-to-open-another-activity-in-android-studio)

Code taken from article:

**Manifest file**

```
<activity
   android:name="MyOtherActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

**Activity.java file**

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button);    

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));
    }
```

});

Comment: In data_layout.xml, there is a button (which is android:id="@+id/button_take_me_there") and when user click the button, it will open new activity. As we can see, the data_layout.xml has no java class, so my question is, is there a way to open new activity?

Comment: That I would be skeptical of.