# How do I make a 'button click action' on one page open the next in Android Studio using Navigation Graphical tool?

Tags: java, android, button, navigation

I'm new to Android Studio and Java programming. I'm stuck trying to figure out how the graphical navigation Resource feature is used to link pages visually. I've made 2 pages for my app each with unique names (e.g. Page1 & Page2). I've also been able to link the two pages visually by dragging and dropping the round circle in the Graphic Navigation panel and named the action (e.g. action 1).

I followed the solutions offered in this thread [How do I get a button to open another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610527/how-do-i-get-a-button-to-open-another-activity-in-android-studio) but none of them worked for me.

This is my button's code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button register_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        register_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_mainActivity_to_registration);
        register_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openRegistrationPage();
            }
        });


    }

    public void openRegistrationPage () {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, registration.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I would want the next page to open when one button is clicked.

Comment: your code is correct, does it open new activity?

Comment: It doesn't. When I run the app on my phone, and click on the button, the app closes.

Comment: Can you share the error log

Comment: How do I get that on my phone? I couldn't make an emulator on my PC

Comment: while you run the app stay connect via adb you can see the error log on Android Studio in Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare your `activities` in `Manifest` file like this

```
   <activity android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY" />
```

And in you `Button` action, make the navigation action like this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY_1.this, YOUR_ACTIVITY_2.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: My Manifest looks like this. I think the declarations were made just as you've suggested automatically.

<activity android:name=".registration" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>