# buttons in fragment(android studio)

Tags: java, android, button, fragment

I'm working on my app, and came to a huge problem. I need to implement buttons in my fragments and can't find a normal solution that works. this is the code:

```
package com.example.konjicdiscover10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);


    }
}
```

and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="60dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="14dp"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="350sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:text="dark mode(in preparation)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="350sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="80dp"
        android:text="Languages(in preparation)"
        android:textSize="11sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

basically what I'm looking for is that a buttons can lead to a new fragments or activities where content will be.

Comment: Hi Deba, maybe this link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67881472/9346054

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32700818/12749998 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13194081/12749998.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add declare a View :

```
package com.example.konjicdiscover10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

View view;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable       ViewGroup container, 
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
myButton..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          //write what you want the button to do
      }
});
return view;

}
}
```

add View :

```
View view;
```

And set the :

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
```

and when you link your xml code with java you will use the 'view' like that :

```
myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

finally you return the view

```
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best practice to implement your buttons in the `onViewCreated` method of the `Fragment` class.

This seems to be the most logical place since you want to implement the buttons as soon as the `view` is created. The benefit of using this method is that you don't have to bother about storing the `View` as variable. The parent class will handle this for you.

Example

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.app.R;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button mOpenButton;
    private Button mCloseButton;

    // constructor
    public SettingsFragment(){
        // require a empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.mOpenButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        this.mCloseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        this.mOpenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SettingsFragment.this.openSomething();
                // in your case: SettingsFragment.this.activateDarkMode();
            }
        });

        mCloseButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                closeSomething();
                // in your case: selectLanguage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openSomething() {
        // in your case: activate dark mode
    }

    private void closeSomething() {
        // in your case: select language
    }
}
```